# Window activation by Title using vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am using a script that:

1. Launches Thunderbird
2. Creates a new message
3. Minimizes the message box
4. Copies the path to the selected folder

**How to activate a minimized Thunderbird message box, knowing its Title?**

The code below does not work:

```js
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe""")  
WScript.Sleep 2000  
WshShell.SendKeys("^n")  
WScript.Sleep 500 
PID = WshShell.AppActivate(WshExec.ProcessID)  
WshShell.Run("notepad")  
If PID Then  
WshShell.SendKeys("^k")  
Else  
MsgBox "Nothing!"  
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

VBS's `AppActivate` wraps the API's `SetForegroundWindow`. Your program MUST comply with one of the following rules to set the active window. Note the standard lockout time is 2 seconds - which is where most people get caught. Note VBScript has no user interface so cannot be the foreground window - you have 2 seconds to set windows after your program starts.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

> **SetForegroundWindow**
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The foreground window is the window at the top of the Z order. It is
>   the window that the user is working with. In a preemptive multitasking
>   environment, you should generally let the user control which window is
>   the foreground window.
>
> Windows 98/Me, Windows 2000/XP: **The system restricts which processes
>   can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window
>   only if one of the following conditions is true:**
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The foreground process is being debugged.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - Windows 2000/XP: No menus are active.
>
> With this change, an application cannot force a window to the
>   foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead,
>   SetForegroundWindow will activate the window (see SetActiveWindow) and
>   call the FlashWindowEx function to notify the user.